# Why is the disordered CuAu structure more stable at high temperatures?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry, x-ray-diffraction

I know that the disordered CuAu structure is based around FCC whereas the ordered CuAu structure is tetragonal. Why would the FCC structure be more stable at high temperatures?

For context, I was asked to explain this with the aid of a graph. I don't really know where to start

Comment: Pretty much ***all*** disordered things are more stable at high temperatures. Think of liquids vs solids, to begin with.

Comment: That makes sense. But why would a closely packed structure ever be more disordered than one which isn't?

Comment: Because _every single atomic position_ in that close-packed structure has some freedom: it may be Cu, or it may be Au. That's a lot of disorder.

Comment: Fabulous , I understand this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a metallurgist or even not a good physical chemist. However, I'd like to explain what's happening in $\ce{AuCu}$ alloy with temperature and any expert can intervene.

According to Ref.1, $\ce{Cu}$ and $\ce{Au}$ are both univalent group IB metals with the atomic size difference ~12%. The $\ce{AuCu}$ alloy forms the tetragonally distorted *fcc* lattice where alternate (00h) planes contain either $\ce{Cu}$ or $\ce{Au}$ atoms and cause a contraction in *c*-direction. Resulting tetragonal face-centered structure has *c/a* ratio of 0.92 $(\frac{c}{a} = \frac{\pu{367 pm}}{\pu{396 pm}} = 0.93)$. In the temperature range ~$\pu{380 ^\circ C}$ to $\pu{410 ^\circ C}$, the superlattice $\ce{CuAu}$-II is formed, which consist of $\ce{CuAu}$-*bct* unit cells with the antiphase domains along the *b*-direction (Ref.2). There is a lattice shift of $\frac12(a+c)$ at each five unit-cell length. The superlattice $\ce{CuAu}$-II is described as orthorhombic cell with 10 cells along one of a direction, $oI40$.

[image: Phase diagram of AuCu alloy]

[image: Calculated diffraction patterns]

Suggested reading: Ref.3 and 4.

---

**References:**

1. Valentina F. Degtyareva, Nataliya S. Afonikova, "Simple Metal and Binary Alloy Phases Based on the *fcc* Structure: Electronic Origin of Distortions, Superlattices and Vacancies," *Crystals* **2017**, *7(2)*, 34 (13 pages) (DOI: https://doi.org/10.3390/cryst7020034).
2. V. Ozoliņš, C. Wolverton, Alex Zunger, "Cu-Au, Ag-Au, Cu-Ag, and Ni-Au intermetallics: First-principles study of temperature-composition phase diagrams and structures," *Phys. Rev. B* **1998**, *57(11)*, 6427 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.57.6427).
3. M. Sanati, L. G. Wang, Alex Zunger, "Adaptive Crystal Structures: $\ce{CuAu}$ and $\ce{NiPt}$," *Phys. Rev. Lett.* **2003**, *90(4)*, 045502 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.90.045502).
4. S. -H. Wei, A. A. Mbaye, L. G. Ferreira, Alex Zunger, "First-principles calculations of the phase diagrams of noble metals: Cu-Au, Cu-Ag, and Ag-Au," *Phys. Rev. B* **1987**, *36(8)*, 4163 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.36.4163).